# Could not open file lol.json: Permission denied using Jq?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, jq

I am facing some kind of permission issue here. I am able to read a file with `cat`, make changes to it using `nano` but for some reason, `jq` is having permission issues. Here is what I am facing:

```
msp@coolpad:~/projects/lol$ jq .name lol.json
jq: error: Could not open file lol.json: Permission denied
```

On checking permissions, this is what I get:

```
msp@coolpad:~/projects/lol$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 msp msp   0 Sep 27 04:04 lol-domains.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 msp msp 593 Sep 27 04:38 lol.json
```

As you can see, I have tried giving it `777` permission, still it's showing `Permission denied`. I know this is not a good idea to set `777` permission and I fully intend to change it back to `664` once the issue is resolved. Anyhelp would be appriciated.

**Update 1:** I have tried re-installing `jq` from `snap` but still, it doesn't solve the problem.

**Update 2:** Output of `cat lol.json`

```
msp@coolpad:~$ cat lol.json
{"name":"lol"}
```

**Update 3:** Output of `echo '{"name":"lol"}' | jq .name`

```
msp@coolpad:~$ echo '{"name":"lol"}' | jq .name
"lol"
```

**Update 4: One work-around that poped up in comments:**

`cat lol.json | jq .name`

Comment: Add output of `cat lol.json` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus just did!

Comment: what about `echo '{"name":"lol"}' | jq .name` ?

Comment: It gives the output, seems like it works with stdin stream

Comment: It seems that your `jq` command does not have the required permissions.

Comment: I did manage to gain a temporary work-around with `cat lol.json | jq .name` thanks to @DiegoTorresMilano. But not sure if that qualifies as an answer to this question

Comment: `chmod 777` [Sigh!](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#gripes) `:-(`

Comment: it works on my machine.

Comment: @anishsane, it was meant to explain the situation here. Even with all permissions, I have absolutely no idea why this is not working. Kindly read the whole question before commenting.

Comment: Try: cat lol.json > lol2.json && jq .name lol2.json

Comment: Add Output of `ls -lZ $(which jq)`to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu did something weird with snaps again. I suggest you install jq from the official website (they have a static binary) or with apt (older version but works)

Comment: @clorz reinstalling from `apt` worked for me, thanks! And actually, on Ubuntu 20.04 `apt` has a more recent version: `snap` installs `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` whereas `apt` installs `jq-1.6`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
sudo snap remove jq
sudo apt install jq
```

Never install command line tools with [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/) without `--classic`. This error is [indented behavior](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement).

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to do one more step (jq was still pointing to `/snap/bin/jq` after... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ so I had to run `source ~/.profile` to clear the error (leaving to help those who come after me:-)